# How to get the duration of captured video using UIImagePickerViewController in Iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need to get the duration of video captured using `UIImagePickerViewController`. Can any one tell me how could it possible to get the duration.

Thanks in advance,
Kiran.